# Create custom group for numeric range in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, grouping

I know that I can achieve what I need with a set of extra columns in the PivotTable Data Source, but I wonder if there is an alternative way to achieve this.

I have a table with Customers Orders; for each order (i.e. each row) I have the customer name and the indication of the nr of days since last order.
I am trying to put up a PivotTable that has the Customer names in the rows, the nr. of orders in the values and the following groups in the columns:

```
    a) < 7 days
    b) 7 <= days < 14
    c) 14 <= days < 28
    d) >= 28 days
```

So far, using the "group field" option, I could create the following groups:

```
    i) < 7 days
    ii) 7 <= days < 14
    iii) 14 <= days < 21
    iv) 21 <= days < 28
```

by setting:

- Starting at = 7
- Ending at = 28
- By = 7

I could live with the extra group (iii), problem is that it does not include the group (d); said differently the grouping acts like a filter which is not what I want.

As said I can add columns for groups a-d, but is there a way to achieve this without?

Comment: Why not just define 4 measures within the model and add those to the Pivot Table Values field, e.g. `7 <= days < 14:=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[Days Since Last Order]>=7,Table1[Days Since Last Order]<14)`, etc.?

Comment: @JosWoolley: thanks; the reason why I am looking for an alternative is that I have more than one case where I would need extra measures and the model is already pretty big.

Comment: Then as far as I know it's not possible to perform uneven groupings within the Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only add one group to a pivot table spaced at a regular interval. What I tend to do in these situations is either add a single column to the data source with a nested if formula or to add a secondary table and use a lookup formula.

For example,
[image]

The formula below finds the group in the secondary table where days are greater than or equal to the lower bound AND less than or equal to the upper bound.

```
=INDEX(Table2[Group],MATCH(1,([@Days]>=Table2[Lbound])*([@Days]<=Table2[Ubound]),0))
```

Comment: thanks, then I guess the answer to my question is "no" :(